# JodConverter with LibreOffice outputs all letteres as squares after docx-to-pdf conversion

Tags: java, pdf, docx, libreoffice, jodconverter

In order to convert docx-files to pdf (or pdf-a to be precise), we are using JodConverter along with LibreOffice. This has been working fine for a week or so, but then suddenly all letters were representet as squares (usually indicating some control-sign) in the converted pdf (the word-file looked fine). After restarting the service for LibreOffice, things went back to normal, and letters were output just fine.

But we were left worried, as we have no guarantee that it won't happen again. I also have no idea why this happened, we had some troubles in the environment prior to this, but none on the server doing the docx-to-pdf convertion in particular.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or a theory as to why it occured?

Answer (score 1):

I have no theory as to why it occured, but I recommend using SoftMaker FreeOffice instead of LibreOffice. All included apps offer direct pdf export and it works excellent. Btw., if you have to exchange documents with Microsoft Office users: this is the office suite with the best interoperability on the market. You get from this website for either Windows or Linux without charge: freeoffice.com/en

Comment: Does it have integration with Java? I need to pass a bytestream representing a docx document and get a corresponding pdf-a bytestream back..